# XSLT ignoring &nbsp; during transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt, saxon

I have a HTML file which I transform with XSL to another HTML file (just tweaking its structure so it looks good in most email clients).

HTML is received from other system and I can't modify how this HTML is generated.

---

My problem is with tags containing `&nbsp;` inside. XSL transformation is ignoring it.

**HTML input:**

```
<span style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue LT 45 Lt', serif; font-size: 12px; color:#000000">
  IMPORTANT: The loan is repayable by 10 payments.&nbsp;The first Direct Debit payment will be collected&nbsp;along with other payments that are already due&nbsp;on...
</span>
```

**HTML output:**

```
<p class="bodytext" align="justify" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:200; font-align:justify;">
  IMPORTANT: The loan is repayable by 10 payments.The first Direct Debit payment will be collectedalong with any other payments that are already dueon...
</p>
```

Both spaces are missing and text is concatenated: `payments.The` and `dueon`.

---

XSL is a bit complex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:character-map name="escape">    
  <xsl:output-character character="&#128;" string="&amp;euro;"/>    
  <xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&amp;nbsp;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" use-character-maps="escape"/>
<xsl:template match="body">
 <html>        
   <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML EMail optimization by" />          
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
...

...
<xsl:template name="TextTemplate">
 <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(.,'XSLTButton'))">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>          
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm using Saxon 9.1.0.8

After some googling I've tried to use `xsl:character-map`,`xsl:preserve-space`, change encoding..  but nothing worked.

The only thing that worked is to add `[<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]` declaration to the DOCTYPE in the INPUT html, but I don't want to create additional step in the process just to add this bit.

Please help. What should I add so XSL/Saxon stop ignoring `&nbsp;`?

Comment: How are you running this transformation?

Saxon accepts input from an XML parser, and it is the job of the XML parser to process entity references such as &npsp;. A standard XML parser will reject such an entity reference if there is no DTD with a declaration of the entity, which appears to be the case in your scenario. Since it seems that the parser in this case is stripping the entity reference rather than rejecting it we need to know how you are running the transformation, and in particular, what XML parser you are using and how it is configured.

Comment: To answer the question a bit more directly, if you don't want Saxon to ignore the `&nbsp;` then you must somehow ensure that the XML parser tells Saxon it is there...

Comment: Thank you for your comment it guided me into the right direction.
We are running transformation like this:
`java -cp %BASEDIR%\lib\* -Dxml.catalog.files=%BASEDIR%\conf\catalog.xml net.sf.saxon.Transform  -r:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver -x:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader -y:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader -o:%output% -s:%input% -xsl:file:%xsl%`

Thanks to your notes here I located local DTD file and add Entity declaration there and its works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTD-aware XML parsers require that entities to which the document refers be declared.  XSLT processing requires that entity references be expanded, so conforming XSLT processors normally use conforming DTD-aware XML parsers for their front end.  If you continue feeding the processing input which uses an undeclared entity, then you are going to continue to get unsatisfactory results.

If the input already has a document type declaration with a reference to an appropriate DTD, then you should try using a DTD-aware parser.  If not, you can inject such a document type declaration, or you can run the HTML through Tidy or some similar processor which assumes the HTML DTD and expands all entity references.

Comment: Yes, input HTMl has a Doctype declaration.
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
We have Resolver which loads local DTD instead of declared one so I've added Entity there and it works (see my comment above). Thanks